# How to catch okhttp3 WebSocket network activity using okhttp3.Interceptor?

Tags: websocket, kotlin, okhttp

I have an okhttp3 (3.9.1) `WebSocket` instance and would like to view all it's network requests and responses. I tried to add some `okhttp3.Interceptor` instances to `OkHttpClient` instance before creating `WebSocket` on it but had no luck in viewing network activity. Here's sample code which demonstrates what I've tried to do:

```
package sample

import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.lang.Thread.sleep

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val listener = object : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, text: String?) {
            println("Got server message: $text")
        }
    }

    val dummyInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        println("Dummy interceptor fired!\n\nRequest: ${request.headers()}\nResponse: ${response.headers()}")
        return@Interceptor response
    }

    val dummyNetworkInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        println("Dummy network interceptor fired!\n\nRequest: ${request.headers()}\nResponse: ${response.headers()}")
        return@Interceptor response
    }

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(dummyInterceptor)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(dummyNetworkInterceptor)
            .build()

    val request = Request.Builder().url("ws://echo.websocket.org").build()

    val webSocket = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, listener)

    webSocket.send("Hello1!")
    webSocket.send("Hello2!")
    webSocket.send("Hello3!")

    sleep(2000) //Just for this sample to ensure all WS requests done
    println("\n\n\tSome network activity\n\n")

    okHttpClient.newCall(Request.Builder().get().url("http://echo.websocket.org").build()).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, exc: IOException?) {
            println("OnFailure: ${exc?.message}")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            println("OnResponse: ${response?.headers()}")
        }
    })
}
```

I tried to dive into okhttp3 source code and didn't find any reason why any of my interceptors doesn't fire on WS requests but works perfectly for any `OkHttpClient` request.

Is it a bug in okhttp3 or am I doing something wrong or it's just not possible to monitor WS requests using `okhttp3.Interceptor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSocket calls made with OkHttp don't use the interceptor chains that HTTP calls do, therefore you can't monitor them through interceptors.

I've faced this issue before myself, and so I looked at the source code and found the following then:

- The regular HTTP calls go through the [`getResponseWithInterceptorChain()`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RealCall.java#L183) method in the `RealCall` class, which quite clearly starts the chained call of interceptors for each request.
- The `okhttp3.internal.ws` package that includes the implementation of the WebSocket handling contains no code related to interceptors.

And really, interceptors catching WebSocket requests wouldn't really make sense in the first place. The `Request` that you can obtain in an interceptor represents an HTTP request, which [WebSocket messages are not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47085864/4465208).

Comment: So...it just isn't possible to even log the requests and responses going through a websocket?

Comment: @amitav13 you always can build a wrapper around your WS instance and log or intercept all requests and responses going through it at the _application_ level (i.e. except internal pings). My question was about intercepting such calls at the _network_ level using existing built-in `OkHttp` intercepters.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible at this point, there's a feature request open for OkHttp but it isn't getting much traction: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4192